# Add Class to Object on Page Load

Tags: javascript, onload

Basically I want to make this:

```
<li id="about"><a href="#">About</a>
```

Into this when the page loads:

```
<li id="about" class="expand"><a href="#">About</a>
```

I found this thread, but am not so good with javascript and couldn't adapt it:
[Javascript: Onload if checkbox is checked, change li class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819814/javascript-onload-if-checkbox-is-checked-change-li-class)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should work:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('about').className = 'expand';
};
```

Or if you're using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#about').addClass('expand');
});
```

Comment: Why are you using += and adding the space in the first example?

Comment: should this go in the head of the page?

Comment: @miles It doesn't matter where you put it, but yeah sure stick it in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) with this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#about').addClass('expand');
});
```

This will add the expand class to an element with id of about when the dom is ready on page load.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest starting to use jQuery just for a simple event handling like this case. Loading jQuery will increase the overall loading time of the page and is not really necessary here.