# How to call function before loading a view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to call a javascript function before loading view content because
I want to add a class "light_theme" in the body tag. 
So I have to add this class before loading the view so that everything can look perfect.

But at the moment AngularJs ads class in body after view is loaded that makes thing little odd.

For example by default theme background color is black but after adding that class it suddenly changes background color and other color schemes suddenly that does not look well.

So that's why I wanted to add that class before view is loaded.
I researched but could not get any good solution.

If this is really possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Class to Object on Page Load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995440/add-class-to-object-on-page-load)

Comment: Consider posting any html/js which you have created

Comment: how is the view loaded?

Comment: view is loaded with state provider

Answer (score 3):

do not use jquery to solve this. you can do it in a run phase, where you have access to the url. if `url == some-url` then add class or else better to add another property named theme on $state object.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, fromState){

    if (toState.theme === "xyz") {
        $('div').addClass('themeClass');
    } else {
        $('div').removeClass('themeClass');
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'resolve' (in state provider config) which will always ensure that function will be called before your views loaded by router (state provider) shown to user

For example you have a view at state 'news', we need call to get message data:

```
.when("/news", {
    templateUrl: "newsView.html",
    controller: "newsController",
    resolve: {
        message: function(messageService){
            return messageService.getMessage();
        }
}
```

Then in newsController you can refer to messageData as a normal injection:

```
app.controller("newsController", function ($scope, message) {
    $scope.message = message;
});
```

Some more info can be found [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `data-ng-init`

In the view you call the `$scope.init()` it will be called on when the view is loaded.

something like this:

```
<div class="wrap-items" data-ng-init="init()">
...
..
</div>
```

Now inside the init function of the scope you can change the class.