# Apply/remove CSS class if parent has specific class

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in CSS 3 to apply/remove a certain *css class* (not property/value) to an element based on it's parent class?

I'll give a concrete example to try and better explain my meaning -  say I have a `<div>` which depending on circumstances I may apply the style-class `my-large-div` or `my-small-div`. Inside it, I some inputs/buttons with the Bootstrap class `form-group` and `form-group-lg`:

```
<div class="my-large-div">
    ...
    <div class="my-form-group form-group form-group-lg">
        <!-- some input field -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, what I want to happen is that when `my-large-div` is applied, the inner div will have `form-group-lg`, but when `my-small-div` is applied, it will not. I conceptually think of a CSS like this:

```
.my-large-div .my-form-group {
    add-class("form-group-lg");
}

.my-small-div .my-form-group {
    remove-class("form-group-lg");
}
```

Now, I know this can be achieved using Javascript/jQuery, but I'm looking for a CSS-only solution, if such a solution exists, or a definitive answer that it can't be done.

One possible solution would be to always have two copies of `my-form-group`, with `display` set to either `none` or `initial`, but I feel this may be messy as well as inefficient (If, say, I change the class in response to user's actions in the page).

One thing I certainly **don't want** to do is to replicate the entire definition of `form-group` and `form-group-lg` in my own CSS, as that would mean with every change of the Bootstrap classes I will have to change mine (plus it breaks the abstraction).

Comment: What is a "css class"? If you're not talking about CSS properties, what are you trying to "remove" from an element?

Comment: Use jQuery, here is an example of adding a class onload. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995440/add-class-to-object-on-page-load

Comment: @BoltClock - I want to use the abstraction the class gives me. The same way I can say "This element should be styled according to this class", thus abstracting away the actual details of the styling to the class, I want to be able to control this entire class structure (whether it's applied or not) according to an element's parent class.  

Instead of doing `.a .b {  /* lot's of properties*/}` I was hoping to do `.a .b { /* now use everything .c calls for */ )`

Comment: @sillyfly: In that case, I think you're simply trying to add or remove the form-group-lg class name from a .form-group element. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701670/can-i-use-non-existing-css-classes/18701712#18701712) explains how classes work. This is not something you can do with CSS, since CSS cannot modify HTML attributes/DOM properties; CSS can only style elements based on document information that is available to it. (I can post this as an answer if you like.)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah by using the `:not()` selector you can do something like

```
.form-group-lg {
    display: none;
}

.my-form-group:not(.my-small-div) .form-group-lg {
    display: block;
}
```

What this does is check if the div with the class `my-form-group` also has a class `my-small-div`, if it doesn't, `form-group-lg` will be displayed as a block, else it will just be `display: none;`

Comment: I don't want to hide the content, just remove the styling that `form-group-lg` entails. It should still be displayed using anything other classes call for.

Comment: In this case wouldn't it be best to have to separate classes to use? Hiding when and showing the other at any time depending on the parent? @sillyfly

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to conditionally asign or remove classes in CSS. Although as you may know, this can be easily accomplished in Javascript.

```
e.g. 
if( $(‘#target’).hasClass(‘animal’) ) {
$(document.body).addClass(‘dog’);
}
```

You can conditionally alter the style of particular classes depending on the parent element however, using the `:not()` selector, as per Samir's example.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. CSS can't remove elements from the DOM, only **Javascript** can access the DOM.

Comment: I don't want it to remove the _element_, just modify it's class. I suspect this as well is impossible, but it's not the same thing.